# Problems replacing values in R data frame

Tags: r

Using Friendman1 function, I want to create a data frame replacing the Target column by values `TRUE`/`FALSE` if value is bigger than / less than or equal to 14.4.

```
library(mlbench)
dataset <- mlbench.friedman1(1600)
colnames(dataset$x) <- paste("Attr.", 1:10, sep="")
data <- data.frame(dataset$x, dataset$y)
colnames(data)[11] <- "Target"

data$Target[data$Target > 14.4] <- "TRUE"
data$Target[data$Target <= 14.4] <- "FALSE"
```

The problem is that it works find except for values < than 10.

So a head result will be:

```
Attr.1 ... Attr.10 Target
0.8356 ... 0.05367 TRUE
0.9723 ... 0.29951 5.7792
0.5623 ... 0.15223 FALSE
```

Comment: You haven't showed us your real code, because your last two lines will both not run since `data` has no column called `Target` at that point. But whatever your code _actually_ is, your problem may be that when you assign the TRUE's (and why character not boolean...?) you have coerced ALL the numeric values to character. So the next line is trying to compare things as characters, not numerically. What you want is to probably to use `ifelse`.

Comment: Yep, sorry I've changed the code to show Target attribute

Comment: The moment you run this `data$Target[data$Target > 14.4] <- "TRUE"` yout variable is not numeric any more. It's tricky to compare it with another number from now on. Try `ifelse(data$Target > 14.4, "TRUE", "FALSE")`.

Comment: As a simple example of how tricky it is to continue treating it as a numeric variable run this: `set.seed(1);
x = runif(10,0,20);
x[x>14.4] = "TRUE";
x;
x[x>14.4] = "TRUE";
x` and see what it returns each time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean recoding all variables? May this approach could be usefull:

```
data %>% 
  mutate_all(.,~case_when(. > 14.4 ~ TRUE, TRUE ~ FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by using `ifelse` function as mention joran.

```
data$Target <- ifelse(data$Target > 14.4, "TRUE", "FALSE")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a data.table solution:

```
setDT(data)
data[, Target := ifelse(Target > 14.4, "TRUE", "FALSE")]
```

I will suggest you to not overwrite an original variable and create a different one with a a new class (character, logical, etc.)